# Mount Hidden From Root User

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, mount

I have a bizarre issue with mount. The root user cannot see a mount that was created by PHP/Apache running a bash script as root.

Steps to recreate the issue:

- Configure fstab for mount point:

  vim /etc/fstab

  /path_to_shared/resource /path_to_local/folder auto defaults,nofail,nobootwait,bind 0 2
- Create a Bash Script.
- Configure Apache to be able to run the bash script as root.
- In bash script mount the shared resource: **mount /path_to_local/folder**

Steps to configure apache to be able to run a script as root:

- visudo
- www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path_to_script/script.sh *

I then run the script (/path_to_script/script.sh) from PHP/Apache.

When the script is done, root is unable to see the contents of the mounted resource (/path_to_shared/resource) inside the mounted folder (/path_to_local/folder).

If I manually run the same command as root, then root is able to see the mount contents. But when the command is run by Apache root is unable to see the contents of the mount, while Apache can see the contents of the mount.

**Example #1:**

In this example, the Apache User is able to see the contents of the mounted folder it mounted using the bash script.

PHP/Apache get directory list:

scandir("/path_to_local/folder")

Shows the contents of /path_to_shared/resource.

**Example #2:**

In this example, the root user is unable to see the contents of the folder that Apache mounted.

root@server~: ls -al /path_to_local/folder

Shows no folder contents.

**Example #3:**

In this example, the root user manually runs the mount command. After doing so, the root user can see the mount. This is an example to show that the same command run as root from a command prompt works.

root@server~: mount /path_to_local/folder

root@server~: ls -al /path_to_local/folder

Shows the contents of /path_to_shared/resource.

**Additional Update**

I found the cause but I don't know what the appropriate solution is. Apparently Apache has a PrivateTmp setting set to true. If I set it to false, it works as I intend it to. However, doing so apparently opens me up to security concerns with the /tmp folder. The info I found was from a similar question/answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869660/bind-mount-not-visible-when-created-from-a-cgi-script-in-apache.

I would prefer to create the mount in realtime instead of waiting on a crontab event. Unless I come up with a real time solution, I'm going to remove the mount command from my Apache script and create the mount with a crontab event.